# Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Recently I bought lap and had done done all the installations and procedures to start working . I have started one using npx react-native init Project and after that I had run it .. it worked initially
Then I changed  and kept a source folder which has navigation that routes to login screen .. and when I run it I am always getting this error.
pls find below img:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

On the Mac for my Flutter projects I have a same issue and I just go to Android Studio and disable NBK Packages.[Packages For Flutter devs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQUsQ.png)

Answer (score 2):

You should add NDK version in 'android/app/build.gradle' if you want to enable it like this

```
android {
    .....

    ndkVersion "22.1.7171670"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run command window `Win + R` and paste

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\SDK
```

Find `ndk` folder and delete all contents inside

> Ex.: 21.0.6113669 folder