# All my programs in Android Studio stop working

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

From one moment to another all my program stop to work in Android Studio and the same message appears all the time. I am new in programming and I don't have any idea how to solve this.
This is all the information I have, if someone could help me would save my day. I can try to find any new information you need to help me.
This is the message:

```
[+3257 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +2 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
[        ] > No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 2s
[{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"df4df21a-9586-4c9e-b613-ec7c7722a318","id":"0","progressId":null,"finished":true}}]
[ +530 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[   +6 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:474:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:977:18)
           #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #11     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
           #12     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #13     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #14     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #15     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #16     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #17     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #18     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #19     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #20     AndroidDevice.isLocalEmulator (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart)
           #21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #23     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #24     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #25     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #26     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #27     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
           #28     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
           #29     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
           #30     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
           #31     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
           #32     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
           #33     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
           #34     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
           #35     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the aswer from this [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28404).
**Open Android Studio -> Preferences -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools -> Show Package Details -> Select "NDK" -> select missing package -> Apply.** If it doesn't work try other answers from the link.

Comment: Have you tried other comments from the link?

Comment: Then you can try [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64290692/execution-failed-for-task-appstripdebugdebugsymbols)